# Rewite fetch function in jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

**The current solution using fetch**

We currently have this function implemented and working perfectly.

```
function setupCKConnect() {

    fetch('ajax/myfile.php?id=1234567')
        .then(response => { 
            response.json()
        .then(json => {
            function1(json)
        .then(data => {
            function2()
        })
        .catch(data => {
            setupCKConnect()
        });
      });
    });

  };
```

**An explanation of the above code**

- The ajax call to myfile.php retrieves a json response used in the function1().
- function1() then listens for a callback from another fucntion (sometimes for up to 10 minutes)
- After function1() receives the callback and is executed, function2() polls the database for a result.

**Why we need to change**

Unfortunately it seems that a significant percentage of our client base use devices which do not support fetch.

Therefore I am trying to rewrite this using jQuery.ajax().

I know this seems like going backwards, but it is necessary in this case.

**The new code**

Below is the code I have so far. Note that Im not married to jQuery for this is someone has a better option.

So far I have this code:

```
function setupCKConnect() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'ajax/myfile.php?id=1234567'
    }).done(function(data) {  
        function1(data)
    }).done(function() {  
        function2()
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
        setupCKConnect()
    });

};
```

**The Problem with the new code**

The new code actually works well except for one small point

- function2() executes immediately, rather than waiting for function1() to complete.

Can anyone help in explaining how to stop function2() executing before function1() has completed

Assistance appreciated

Comment: Could you fix your syntax? It’s illegal to have the sequence `;.` near `json();.then(`.

Comment: yes sorry... fixed

Comment: https://github.com/github/fetch how far back does your browser support go? this polyfill takes care of IE 10 and 11.

Comment: Its mainly older versions of safari on iphones that is the issue... many of our clients have pre 2017 iphones and seem never to have updated anything

Answer (score -1):

So the ajax response returns a deferred object and not a promise. These look similar, but mixing the two can be wonky. I've created a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r26pdgjc/) based on the [deferred.done documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) to illustrate what I mean.

I would venture to guess that `function1(json)` returns a promise. The deferred gets a value back (the unresolved promise) and thinks "great lets move on" You either need to async/await or call then on that function call for the execution to pause for anything else.

Answer (score -1):

If you fix the indentation of your original code, you'll see the problem. The call to `function2()` is not in a `.then()` that's chained to the first `.then()`, it's called on the result of `function1()`. And `.catch()` is also called from there, not from `fetch()`, so you can't use `.fail()` as a replacement.

```
function setupCKConnect() {
  fetch('ajax/myfile.php?id=1234567')
    .then(response => {
      response.json()
        .then(json => {
          function1(json)
            .then(data => {
              function2()
            })
            .catch(data => {
              setupCKConnect()
            });
        });
    });
};
```

So you need to structure the jQuery code similarly.

```
function setupCKConnect() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'ajax/myfile.php?id=1234567'
    }).done(function(data) {  
        function1(data)
            .then(function(data) {
                function2()
            })
            .catch(function() {  
                setupCKConnect(data)
            });
    })
};
```

This assumes that `function1()` is similar to the original version, so it returns a promise just like that does.